# Using ElasticSearch as alternative data store with applications updating both the DB and ES(with the help of Kafka). Is this a good idea?

Tags: elasticsearch, architecture, logstash, apache-kafka, software-design

The architecture is like this, there are several applications which access some set of relational Databases. But some applications require large joins which increases the query time. To solve this problem we made a ElasticSearch copy of the relational DBs. But even real time indexing of data in ES from DB takes a lot of time. 
Which is where Kafka comes, we introduce a Kafka pipeline connecting applications directly to ES. Logstash for ES is a consumer and applications are producers for the Kafka. Alongside the normal flow which updates DB is intact (So if ES index crashes or ES cluster loses data in any way we can update back from DB)
Is this kind of architecture a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a good idea, yes, for reasons that you mention yourself. In fact, I also have a setup where docs are fed into ES through Kafka and can't really imagine going back to the setup I had before introducing Kafka.

If you're going to need a finer grain control over Kafka consumption process, take a look [here](https://github.com/reachkrishnaraj/kafka-elasticsearch-standalone-consumer). That's a recent project that unfortunately became usable after I implemented my own low-level consumers :)